# MATLAB: Concatenation error in for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, 3d, concatenation

I am making 3D grids out of 2D swath data in MATLAB.
I have given a very short representation here:

```
for p=1:30
    for hh=1:125
        ZI{hh} = data(:)
        ZZZ = cat(3, ZI{:})
    end 
end
```

When I am giving dates, i.e, `p` as a single value (i.q 1/2) in for loop to concatenate 2D `ZI` matrices for all  heights (`hh`), the code is running, and it is producing 3D `ZZZ`, but for `p=1:3` or any other value, after only one iteration of `p`, the following error is produced:

```
Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
Error in Precip_column_2 (line 103)
ZZZ = cat(3, ZI{:});
```

Comment: what is size of data(:) ? Also, in your code, you are running loop for p, but you are overwriting the results.

Comment: I have to make data sets for 365 days, and the size of ZZZ will be 350x400x125, where the first dimention is for latitude, 2nd is for longitude and third is for height.The code is too long so that I have just put some brief information here.

Comment: size of data{;} is 350x400 and p which is given 1:30 can be go upto 365 as this is the date information

Comment: Check whether the cell contents of ZI{hh} all have the same number of elements. If I set `data = rand(350,400)` then this code executes without errors.

Comment: You may have some other reason for keeping it there, but it looks like the call to `cat()` could be moved into the outer loop. Does that help? Without more information it is difficult to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thank you all specially Dennis  for the help :) It is running now, after I moved the cat() in outer loop and cleared the ZI{} after the cat is done it is now catenating for all iterations of p, somehow the values kept storing in ZI, though the first three lines of my code always gives, clc, close and clear.